# How to rename the NIB file (or xib so it renames the nib)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

This is the result of my run below.  A few days ago, I renamed some of the objects (including the .xib file) and for some reason, XCode 4 found one I didn't rename?  (I'm guessing because it says it can't load it).  How do I find the names of the NIB, or change the xib file so it names the nib correctly?

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 27080.
2011-03-11 09:43:00.142 PointsEncodeDecode[27080:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/4066ECCF-3937-49B1-9FBE-1CE9BFA56844/PointsEncodeDecode.app> (loaded)' with name 'ReaderSampleViewController''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing Nib doesn't seem to be the main Nib file for the application the name of which is specified in the Info.plist file. Perhaps another Nib file has the old Nib name for creating an external object in it. I would first delete the entire `build` directory, and grep all text reference to the old filename in Terminal to find out who still has the reference to it.

```
grep -rnF '<old Nib name>' <path_to_your_project_directory>
```

Comment: Does the NIB get built by the XIB?

Comment: Yes. Precisely speaking I should've used the term Xib as it's before the Xib-to-Nib conversion. But since someday I get used to use the two terms interchangeably....